# Reading bulk Excel files from a file with Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have 40 .xls files in a folder I would like to import into a df in Pandas.

Is there a function similar to read_csv() that will allow me to direct Python to the folder and open each of these files into the dataframe? All headers are the same in each file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) to open each file. You can loop over the files using the [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
dfs = {}
for f in glob.glob('*.xlsx'):
    dfs[f] = pd.read_excel(f)
df = pd.concat(dfs) # change concatenation axis if needed
```

Answer (score 0):

you can load excel files and [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) each other.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

files = os.listdir(<path to folder>)
df_all = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(f"<path to folder>/{file}")
    df_all = pd.concat([df_all,df])
```

Answer (score 0):

`import os import pandas as pd`

`folder = r'C:\Users\AA\Desktop\Excel_file' files = os.listdir(folder)`

`for file in files: if file.endswith('.xlsx'): df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(folder,file))`

Does this help?

Comment: The formatting of your code is messed up. You can copy your block of code and indent it all with 4 space for it to be recognized as code.